# Javascript: Calculate 2 User Defined Date Fields

Tags: javascript, jquery, date, math

OK, so I decided on the JavaScript approach here:

### OBJECTIVE:

Have the user select 2 dates (`dateFrom` and `dateTo`) from the JQuery date picker and the dates would populate those respective fields. Then the script would automatically display the total days between those two fields.  This is my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function days_between(dateFrom, dateTo) {
  var ONE_DAY = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24
  var dateFrom_ms = dateFrom.getTime()
  var dateTo_ms = dateTo.getTime()
  var difference_ms = Math.abs(dateFrom_ms - dateTo_ms)
  return Math.round(difference_ms/ONE_DAY)
}

</script>
```

Not getting any errors, just not displaying.

Comment: You need to call the function in oder for that to execute.

Comment: Could you please create a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) with all of your current code?

Comment: How are you trying to display your result?

Comment: You know that you've forgotten every semicolon in your code, right?

Comment: You need to pass obj date for params and call the function